# How to check if a character is within a range of characters?

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate over a string and check whether a character at a specific index is within a range of letters; "a" through "m" in the alphabet.

Is there a quick way to do this instead of declaring a new string or object and writing out all the letters within my desired range and checking to see if the current letter is a character within that string or object?

```
/* str takes in a string of characters such as 'askjbfdskjhsdkfjhskdjhf'
     count each time a character exists thats not a letter between a-m in the alphabet */

   function countOutOfRange(str) {
          // count each time a letter shows up thats not within a range of letters
   }
```

Comment: So you want to know if some character is >= 'a' and <= 'm'?

Comment: yes @ScottHunter

Comment: I know how to check it, I just want a more concise solution, I'm not sure if there is a more concise solution

Comment: Your question says _"is __within__ a range of letters"_ but then _"count each time a character exists that's __not__ a letter between a-m"_. Which is it?

Comment: Whether it detects within a range or without of, I'll be able to utilize the code in the manner I'm hoping for. For this case, lets just say a character is NOT within the range of characters. @Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex to return the length of the returned array where letters are not within your range.

```js
function counter(str) {
  return str.match(/[^a-m]/g).length;
}

console.log(counter('zhuresma'));
console.log(counter('bob'));
console.log(counter('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'));
```

If you want it to be more flexible:

```js
function counter(str, range) {
  const query = `[^${range[0]}-${range[1]}]`;
  const regex = new RegExp(query, 'g');
  return str.match(regex).length;
}

console.log(counter('zhuresma', ['a', 'b']));
console.log(counter('bob', ['a', 'm']));
console.log(counter('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ['y', 'z']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to loop through each character in the given string.

```js
/* str takes in a string of characters such as 'askjbfdskjhsdkfjhskdjhf'
     count each time a character exists thats not a letter between a-m in the alphabet */

function countOutOfRange(sentence, beginChar, endChar) {
  // count each time a letter shows up thats not within a range of letters
  
  let sum  = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
      if (sentence.charCodeAt(i) > beginChar.charCodeAt(0) && 
          sentence.charCodeAt(i) < endChar.charCodeAt(0))
          sum++;
  }
  
  return sum;
}

console.log(countOutOfRange('askjbfdskjhsdkfjhskdjhf', 'a', 'm'));
```

Comment: You don't need `charCodeAt` - the default behavior for string greater than/less than comparison is already lexicographical comparison.